# Seeing cl.exe command line WITHOUT verbosity "detailed"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I have two Visual Studio C++ projects that build libraries.

They both have Options-->Projects and Solutions-->Build And Run-->MSBuild project build output verbosity  set to "Normal."

And yet one outputs the cl command line options (including, for instance, expanded environment variables) while the other doesn't.

Where would this setting be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setting is in the project properties.

Right-click on the project in question, and set Properties-->Configuration Properties-->C/C++-->General-->Suppress Startup Banner to **no**.

You probably will also want to set Properties-->Configuration Properties-->C/C++-->General-->Suppress Startup Banner  to **no** too.  (The help text for this option even in Visual Studio 2019 simply mentions that it prevents display of the copyright message and version number, but it does more than that.)